# Java spawning Ghost Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I'm working on a new NLP Classifier algorithm and want to make it multithreaded. My implementation performs what it should do correctly but I get some weird exceptions when run with threads=4.
This is my method:

```
protected void generateCoordinatesMultiThread(Category generate, int threads){
    WordMap wordMap = new WordMap();
    wordOccurences = new int[semanticspace.getVectorAmount()][generate.getSize()];
    tfidf = new double[semanticspace.getVectorAmount()][generate.getSize()];
    ntfidf = new double[semanticspace.getVectorAmount()][generate.getSize()];
    Thread[] threadGroup = new Thread[threads];
    try{
        System.out.println(generate.getSize()+" objects in "+threads+" threads");
        for(int i=0;i<threads;i++){
            int start=(generate.getSize()/threads)*i;
            int end=((generate.getSize()/threads)*(i+1))-1;
            if(i==threads-1){
                end=generate.getSize();
            }
            System.out.println("Start: "+start+" end: "+end);
            threadGroup[i] = new Thread(new WordMapper(this,start,end,generate,"WordMapper-"+i,wordMap));
            threadGroup[i].start();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<threads;i++){
            threadGroup[i].join();
        }
        System.out.println("First multi-thread step finished");
        wordMap.mapSemanticSpace(semanticspace);
        wordMap.print();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Starting frequency workers");
    threadGroup = new Thread[threads];
    try{
        System.out.println(generate.getSize()+" objects in "+threads+" threads");
        for(int i=0;i<threads;i++){
            int start=(generate.getSize()/threads)*i;
            int end=((generate.getSize()/threads)*(i+1))-1;
            if(i==threads-1){
                end=generate.getSize();
            }
            System.out.println("Start: "+start+" end: "+end);
            threadGroup[i] = new Thread(new FrequencyWorker(this,start,end,generate,"FrequencyWorker-"+i,wordMap));
            threadGroup[i].start();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<threads;i++){
            threadGroup[i].join();
        }
        System.out.println("Second multi-thread step finished");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Starting coordinate generators");
    threadGroup = new Thread[threads];
    try{
        System.out.println(generate.getSize()+" objects in "+threads+" threads");
        for(int i=0;i<threads;i++){
            int start=(generate.getSize()/threads)*i;
            int end=((generate.getSize()/threads)*(i+1))-1;
            if(i==threads-1){
                end=generate.getSize();
            }
            System.out.println("Start: "+start+" end: "+end);
            threadGroup[i] = new Thread(new CoordinateGenerator(this,start,end,generate,"FrequencyWorker-"+i,wordMap));
            threadGroup[i].start();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<threads;i++){
            threadGroup[i].join();
        }
        System.out.println("Third multi-thread step finished");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This gives me the exceptions:

> Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at semanticobjects.WordMapper.run(WordMapper.java:21)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

Same with 9 and 13. Both are numbers that should not have been generated in the first place when running with threads=4. Also the resulting calculations are correct. I just get this exception. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please point out whith line throws exception - mark `WordMapper.java:21`

Comment: What makes you think the theads are ghost threads? If it's the thread number, note that this number is just a static int that gets incremented, i.e. if you rerun that method the numbers will be greater (and Thread-1 probably is the main thread, so the 4 new threads should be named Thread-2 to Thread-5). If you want the threads to have the same names when calling that method again provide a name to the constructor.

Comment: @SirTobiSwobi but to be honest it would be much simpler for you to use `ExecutorService` and `Callable` tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Java 5 there is a new (not so new already) package: `java.util.concurrent`. In that package there are a lot of tools that make your life much simple when working with multi-threading. In particular there are several options to get an out-of-the-box thread pools. Look at [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class API and [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) class API. Read about various implementations of ExecutorService available. It takes a bit of getting used to, but once you get a hold of the concept, it takes away all the tedious work of thread management, and all you have to do is to worry about your implementation logic. It also makes your code simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you will look into the Thread.class you will see following code:

```
    public Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target) {
          init(group, target, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
    }

    /* For autonumbering anonymous threads. */
    private static int threadInitNumber;
    private static synchronized int nextThreadNum() {
        return threadInitNumber++;
    }
```

So as you can see, everytime you create new thread, it will have unique name that is created using static field `threadInitNumber` - remember that static fields are shared across all the instances of given class.

Your `threadCount=4` means that you will create 4 threads at once, but you are doing it couple of times, 3 to be exact, and 3x4 equals 12 - that is the reason of creating "ghost" threads in your opinion. You are creating 12 threads not 4 but not at once. Now why thre thread is named 13 insteed of 12? Well because rest of your application must have had created new thread prior of calling `generateCoordinatesMultiThread`